# How to fix shader warping and stretching on uv sphere

Tags: uv, shaders, coordinates, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

I'm learning procedurally generated shaders, and have a few questions related to Object/uv coordinates. I'm having some problems with stretching and an obvious seem. I've been messing around with this for enough time so I thought I'd see if I could get some help on this.

I would like these patterns to be evenly distributed with no stretching or warping.

- For the stretching issue using object coordinates, I've tried remapping the vector and messing around with the scale.
- For the uv seem, I've tried uv unwrapping a few different ways.

1. Preferred results for Object coordinate:

- The pattern behaves similarly to uv coordinates where it isn't stretched and the scale looks
  correct.

2. Preferred result for UV coordinate:

- Hide the seem so if I increase the scale of the pattern or rotation the seem doesn't show.

I'd love to use Object coordinates as it looks like the best solution for manipulation of the pattern. Just the stretching is a major issue haha

[image: uv seem1]
[image: object coordinate stretching]

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand you correctly, but I'm guessing that you want to distribute the texture evenly across your *UV Space*.

If I have crystallized this correctly, you would actually only need the `Mapping` node in your setup and adjust the scaling accordingly.

You place the node immediately after the `Texture Coordinates` node and use the number of repetitions divided by $\pi$ as the scaling on the *X axis*, and half of it for the *Y axis*.

> Tip: you can enter the number $\pi$ in all fields by simply writing the letters "pi" instead of a numerical value.

[image]

If this answer helps you, please be so kind and edit your question again, so that others better understand what it is about.

Comment: Thank you!!! Sorry for not clearly asking my question but you were able to parse through that and solve this! Really appreciate you taking a look at this :)

Comment: Wonderful! It would be great if you could rephrase the title of your question so that others might understand the task better.